# Send an email and ReplyAll to it

Tags: vba, email, outlook

My task is to send an email containing a report and send another email containing another report to the same email thread by way of replying/forwarding to the sent email *(excluding some recipients)*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestReply()

    Dim objApp As Application
    Dim objNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNewMail = objApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Outgoing email
    With objNewMail
        .Subject = "Test sending email"
        .To = "abc@abc.com"
        .HTMLBody = "This is the outgoing email."
        .Send
    End With

    ' Reply email
    Set objReply = objNewMail.ReplyAll
    With objReply
        .HTMLBody = "This is the reply emal."
        .Display
    End With

    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNewMail = Nothing
    Set objReply = Nothing
End Sub
```

I can't find a way to send the follow up email (either by reply or forward).

When I try the above code, it says error the item is moved/deleted. I guess it is becaused when the email is sent, the `objNewMail` odject is also terminated.

I tried adding **RE:** or **FW:** to the subject of the original email but then the two emails will not be in the same thread but independent emails.

An additional problem is that I have two email accounts in Outlook: **my own** email and **team** email and the reports are to be sent from the **team** email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if an item added to the sent folder matches objNewMail.

In ThisOutlookSession

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents sentFolderItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    'Set sentFolderItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items

    ' Reference any folder by walking the folder tree
    '  assuming the team folder is in the navigation pane
    Set sentFolderItems = Session.folders("team mailbox name").folders("Sent").Items

End Sub


Private Sub sentFolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim myReplyAll As MailItem

    If Item.Class = olMail Then

        'do not use InStr unless you change some part of words in original subject
        ' or another reply will be generated
        If Item.Subject = "Test sending email" Then
            Set myReplyAll = Item.ReplyAll

            With myReplyAll
                .HTMLBody = "This is the reply email."
                .Display
            End With
        End If

    End If

End Sub


Sub TestReply()

    Dim objNewMail As MailItem

    'Set objNewMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)

    ' Add, not create, in non-default folder
    Set objNewMail = Session.folders("team mailbox name").folders("Inbox").Items.Add

    ' Outgoing email
    With objNewMail
        .Subject = "Test sending email"
        .To = "abc@abc.com"
        .HTMLBody = "This is the outgoing email."
        .Send
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: `Application.` and `Outlook.` are not needed when code is in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Call Send on the original email (objNewMail) only *after* you construct the reply.

Comment: I have already tried that. But even if I try to construct the reply before sending the original email `objNewMail`, it still hit me with error saying: _Could not send the message._ (although I have not *Send* or *Display* it yet)

Comment: The debugger points the error to line `Set objReply = objNewMail.ReplyAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Right so currently your code is doing this:

1. Creating a mail, sending it.
2. Trying to reply to the mailitem object which is already sent.

What you need is an event Hook to catch the mail when it's received by yourself. (assuming this is how you're reply all and removing some recipients for report 2)

Here is how you accomplish this:

First Create a WithEvents as Items call AllMyItems, then a hook in the AllMyItems_ItemAdd, then initialize the event when Outlook Starts using Application_Startup (a built in event)

**Be very careful to identify criteria for forwarding / actioning the incoming mail item, since this event code will scan every mail sent to your main inbox and evaluate it. IF you want to further reduce the risk of forwarding a mail item to the wrong person, consider using an outlook rule to sort it into a custom folder, and then setting that folder's location as the  Set AllMyItems = line instead of default folder**

```
Option Explicit
'for the Default DL inbox
Private WithEvents AllMyItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olapp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  'Set myolitems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

    'all my items in the main box
    Set AllMyItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    Set olapp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
 End Sub

Private Sub AllMyItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error Resume Next
  If TypeName(Item) <> "Mailitem" Then
  If TypeName(Item) = "ReportItem" Then GoTo 0 'undeliverables shows as a report item
  If TypeName(Item) = "MeetingItem" Then GoTo 0

  Dim oItem As MailItem
  Dim myForward As MailItem
  Set oItem = Item
  'use the next line to check for a property of the incoming mail, that distinguishes it from other mail, since this event will run on every mail item
  If InStr(1, oItem.Subject, "Your public folder is almost full", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set myForward = oItem.Forward
    myForward.Recipients.Add "derp@derpinacorp.com"
    myForward.Importance = olImportanceHigh
    'MsgBox "uno momento"
    myForward.Send

  Else

  End If

  Else

  End If
  0:
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is I'm sending the report using a team email account (added in outlook) so I'm not sure this code will monitor **my** mail boxes or **all** mail boxes (*including* the team account).

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` has no purpose. It causes no damage in this case but usually does. You could remove it http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm.

Comment: There is a typo in `If TypeName(Item) <> "Mailitem" Then`. It should be MailItem with a capital I. You may apply LCase or UCase when strings are involved `If LCase(TypeName(Item)) = LCase("Mailitem")`. Note the equal sign can be used now.